# The reply address 'xxx/signout-callback-oidc' does not match the reply address 'x:xx/signin-oidc' provided when requesting Authorization code

Tags: .net

Not sure why only when I use the Incognito mode, I will get this error message.

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> MsalServiceException: A configuration issue is preventing
> authentication - check the error message from the server for details.
> You can modify the configuration in the application registration
> portal. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-invalid-client for details.
> Original exception: AADSTS500112: The reply address
> 'https://localhost:123/signout-callback-oidc' does not match the reply
> address 'https://localhost:123/abc/signin-oidc' provided when
> requesting Authorization code.

But if it is non-incognito mode, it works without any error.

These are some code from Program.cs (.NET 6)

```
var graphScope = builder.Configuration["GraphSettings:Scope"]?.Split(' ');

builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(builder.Configuration, "AzureAd")
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(graphScope)
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;

});

builder.Services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.All;
    options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
    options.KnownProxies.Clear();
});
```